# Using tags/keywords in Sphinx/Jinja to create a page which contains a list of links to all other pages containing said tag/keyword

Tags: python, jinja2, python-sphinx

OK, I feel like this should be explained in some obvious place but I have searched and found nothing (and I always found an answer for my previous 999 problems, so normally I am not bad at searching).

Basically, I am making a manual for my physical product, the Foomaster. The manual contains a range of information (individual .rst files) on the Foomaster, which are organised (using toctree in index.rst and other .rst sub structure files) by physical location on the Foomaster.  Some of these pages are service procedures, some are safety warnings, some are general information.

Now I would like to create a separate page, monthly_service.rst, which lists all of the pages (.rst files) which describe a service procedure which should be checked monthly. This list of monthly procedures would not be broken if the 'destination' page is moved (i.e. it would find where the rst is located based on the inclusion of a tag, and then create the link to this location).  For example, with pseudocode:

---

```
change_foobulb.rst

.. tag:: monthly_maintenance

(description of how to change foobulb)
```

---

```
clean_footank.rst

.. tag:: monthly_maintenance

(description of how to clean footank)
```

---

```
monthly_service.rst

Make sure the following procedures are followed at least monthly:

.. maketocusing::
   tags: monthly_maintenance
```

---

Apologies if this is already explained somewhere... I found explanations on .. index:: directive which led me to try adding:

```
.. index::
   single: monthly
```

to each of change_foobulb and clean_footank rst files.  The result of this was addition of an entry in the index (under 'M') of 'monthly, [1]', with links to both pages - i.e. they were treated as duplicated index entries, as I suppose is the purpose of the index directive.  Since this does not show the name of each monthly process (like a toctree, and presented in a separate 'monthly.rst' page), this was not useful for my case.

I also found that someone created a custom .. tag:: directive but as far as I understood this is not used to dynamically generate such a list of links - I think it was rather used for deciding what pages to include when building the HTML when using make.bat.

I guess it might need some Jinja solution, but I'm not too strong in Jina... thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It seems like you want an index (or something similar). But all you say about that is *"but that did not work"*. That is not a useful problem description. Please explain exactly what you tried.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment!  True, that was lazy - I have expanded that part to hopefully explain why the index directive did not work for me.  I have also added a bit more to the question in general.

Comment: Further: yes you are right, the need is quite similar to an index functionality. The index directive correctly generates the links - however instead of just adding them to the index under 'M', I would need a separate 'Monthly maintenance' page (cosmetic difference I guess, but important in this case) and the links to the page would use the actual title of the rst file (instead of 'monthly' and '[1]').
Thanks again for your time